# Difference between "one" and "the one"

Tags: difference, articles

Could anyone please tell me the difference between **one** and **the one**?

1- He is **one** who committed many crimes.

2- He is **the one** who committed many crimes.

3- He is **one** who killed two people.

4- He is **the one** who killed two people.

Comment: "He is one who..." is a rather formal way of saying "He is a person who...". It could just as well be left out. "He committed many crimes."  "The one" identifies him as a particular person whose crimes we know about. So (3) means "He is a double murderer", and (4) means "He is guilty of a [particular] double murder.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One" can act as an indefinite article, like "a". For example, "an apple" or "a banana" is the same as saying "*one* apple" or "*one* banana". As a pronoun, it can refer to a non-specific individual, such as the average person. Without the definite article "the", "one" doesn't make a person or a thing *unique*.

So, saying "he is one who committed a crime" means he is *not the only person* who committed a crime - perhaps he is *one of many*. Saying "he is *the* one who committed a crime" singles him out as a specific individual, perhaps unique among a group, that did so.

In your second example where you refer to the killing of two people, saying "he is *one*" who did this would mean he is one of many who have killed two people. If you add in the definite article and say "he is *the* one who killed two people", you are referring to a specific case, and so the two people killed are also by default a specific pair.